# RabbitMQ shovels badmatch for anything other than default uri

Tags: rabbitmq, rabbitmq-shovel

I am on RMQ version 3.6.0.

Creating a shovel using the default 'amqp://' uri for source and target, and the default '/' v-host works fine.

However whenever I use a different vhost, or a different user it doesn't work. This includes stating the default v-host explicitly using %2F also. I tried with and without %2F for both the default v-host and the other v-host. I tried going from the default vhost to the new vhost and visa versa.
I tried with and without username, password and made an admin account with a simple password to rule out % encoding issues of the password. I tried with and without the host (domain name). I tried with and without the cluster name. I tried with and without the port (5672).

Despite trying all these combinations, the shovel is stuck in starting state, because of a badmatch error:

`crasher:
    initial call: gen:init_it/6
    pid: <0.27614.7287>
    registered_name: []
    exception exit: {{badmatch,{error,etimedout}},
                     [{rabbit_shovel_worker,make_conn_and_chan,1,
                          [{file,"src/rabbit_shovel_worker.erl"},{line,236}]},
                      {rabbit_shovel_worker,handle_cast,2,
                          [{file,"src/rabbit_shovel_worker.erl"},{line,62}]},
                      {gen_server2,handle_msg,2,
                          [{file,"src/gen_server2.erl"},{line,1049}]},
                      {proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,
                          [{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,240}]}]}
      in function  gen_server2:terminate/3 (src/gen_server2.erl, line 1160)
    ancestors: [<0.3813.7286>,<0.536.0>,rabbit_shovel_dyn_worker_sup_sup,
                  rabbit_shovel_sup,<0.532.0>]
    messages: []
    links: [<0.3813.7286>]
    dictionary: [{random_seed,{26721,25702,22425}}]
    trap_exit: false
    status: running
    heap_size: 987
    stack_size: 27
    reductions: 1577
  neighbours:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, just for anyone else who comes across this problem.

It actually ended up being the old %2F problem.

the vhost was named '/dev'

The source and target URI of

`amqp:///%2Fdev`

For vhosts without the slash, it was just eg

`amqp:///dev`

worked in the end.